# Windows Phone Emulator messing up..?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to get into Windows Phone 7.5/8 application development. I'm having an issue with my emulator, mainly it is showing up weird when I launch my app for debugging, and now is throwing errors like this (my code is working, I know that, not sure why it's showing that error):

[image: Old Screenshot]

---

Sorry, I found an error in my code that was keeping it from displaying the typed text, but it still is messing up the emulator after I fixed the code. See the new screenshot:

[image: New Screenshot]

Basically, when I click on any keyboard buttons on the OSK, the button sticks (doesn't keep typing, but sticks visually). Also, as you can see, the entire application doesn't show up, only places where there is an element on the screen. Any idea(s)?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

Ok, so here is a few more images of the issue, with a different app that doesn't use the TextBox controller. If still needed, I can supply both the code for the TextBox app and the new one.
Thanks!
[image: before-click]
[image: after-click]

Comment: Questions that basically say "I have a problem. Please go somewhere else to see what I'm talking about, and then come back here and give me an answer" are not proper for this site. Please edit your question and provide more information *here* about the problem you're having with the emulator. "I'm having an issue...mainly it's showing up weird" won't be useful at all to future readers who have a problem and are searching for help getting it solved. Thanks.

Comment: Ken, I've updated the post. But I cannot upload images yet, so the only way for me to show you guys what the issue is is to point to an off-site website for the image hosting.

Comment: I went ahead and cleaned up your post for you, as well as inlining your screenshots.

Comment: Thanks Adam! Hopefully now someone will be able to help me fix the issue :)

Comment: Do u have any keydown etc events registered for the TextBox ? if so, show the code inside those handlers. If not, try to create a new project and create a plain TextBox without any additional styles and observe how it behaves

Comment: It behaves like this with or without the text box (minus the keyboard of course) I will get a few more screenshots later today, as I'm not in Windows right now. Working on getting Windows 8 installed today, then hopefully I won't have to deal with this issue anymore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you are running on a system that has the Intel GMA 4000. The problem is with the graphics driver and I don't think they have been updated. There's a work around for you to take the screenshots of the app properly:

1. Download the Silverlight Windows Phone Toolkit here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888
2. Install it.
3. In your project, add the reference to the file `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll` located in:
4. In the `App.xaml.cs` (under the `App.xaml`), go to the line

`RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();`

and change it to:

`RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();`
5. Run the emulator, and the glitch graphics are off.

When you want to publish your app, or test in other ambient or device, you must restore the line that we change to its original state. (I don’t know what it does, but certainly, it is in a region that the users should not touch).

Comment: Thanks! I will try that as soon as I get a chance. Yes, I do have Intel 4000 graphics (a mid 2012 MacBook Pro running Windows 7, soon to be Windows 8)